# Include multiple items in one command line argument

Tags: node.js, bash, shell

I have an executable called suman -

```
suman --runner --exec-args="--harmony --expose-gc" test/src/a.js --inherit-stdio
```

I want to include `"--harmony --expose-gc"` and pass this to `--exec-args`, but right now it's taking `"--expose-gc"` instead.

Anyone know how to pass the whole string to that argument?

I tried this too:

```
suman --runner --exec-args='"--harmony --expose-gc"' test/src/a.js --inherit-stdio
```

and this:

```
suman --runner --exec-args="'--harmony --expose-gc'" test/src/a.js --inherit-stdio
```

Still didn't take.

Comment: Why do you think only `--expose-gc` is passed as argument?

Comment: That's what I get when I log it

Comment: Looks like a internal problem of your program to me. `--exec-args="--harmony --expose-gc"` passes the string `--exec-args=--harmony --expose-gc` as the second argument to your program. You can replace `suman` by a bash script, which executes `echo "$2"`, to verify this.

Comment: Yeah, I think what then happens is that my CLI parser sees --expose-gc as isolated, and then complains that it's not a valid argument. somehow I need "--harmony --expose-gc" to be data as one string.

Comment: @AlexanderMills  Your script is passing the data as a single string, there is nothing more it can do to prevent `suman` from doing what it does when parsing the data.  Either `suman` has a bug/limitation (i.e. not able te receive more than one option), or it has a different syntax for that (i.e. being able to receive `--exec_args` more than once, like `--exec-args='--harmony' --exec-args='--expose-gc'`, or requiring a comma-separated list of options instead of space-separated).